# How to find the matrix elements of $ \hat{P}^2 $ in the $X$ basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

In a resolution of a question in Shankar's book (https://www.physicspages.com/pdf/Shankar/Shankar%20Exercises%2005.01.02.pdf), the derivation of the matrix elements of $ P^2 $ is obtained as follows

$$  \langle x|P^2|\psi\rangle = \int \int \langle x|P|x' \rangle \langle x'|P|x'' \rangle \langle x''|\psi \rangle dx'dx'' \\ = \int \int \langle x|P|x' \rangle (-i \hbar \frac{d}{dx'} \delta (x'-x''))\psi(x'')dx'dx'' \\ = -i \hbar \int \langle x|P|x' \rangle \frac{d \psi(x')}{dx'}dx' \\ = -i \hbar \int (-i \hbar \frac{d}{dx} \delta (x-x'))\frac{d \psi(x')}{dx'}dx' \\ = - \hbar^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x).  $$
I don't know what was done from the second line to the third.
I have tried to use this relation for dirac delta(which is obtained by integrating by parts)
$$ [\frac{d}{dx} \delta (x-a)]f(x) = - \delta (x-a)\frac{df(x)}{dx} $$
but I didn't get it.

Comment: It is simply $\int dx'' \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(\delta (x'-x''))\psi(x'')=\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\int dx'' \delta (x'-x'')\psi(x'')$ since $\partial\psi(x'')/\partial x'=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split up the integrand and first perform the integral w.r.t $x^{\prime\prime}$.

$$\int\int\langle x|P|x^\prime\rangle(-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx^\prime} \delta(x^\prime-x^{\prime\prime}))\psi(x^{\prime\prime})dx^\prime dx^{\prime\prime}$$

We can just ignore the $d/dx^\prime$ for now, since they should commute. The scalar terms not involving $x^{\prime\prime}$ brought outside as well, we just compute

$$\int \delta(x^\prime-x^{\prime\prime})\psi(x^{\prime\prime}) dx^{\prime\prime} = \psi(x^\prime)$$

And that should give you your answer

Comment: Maybe I understood it. But does $ \frac{d}{dx'} $ commute with $ \delta(x'-x'') $ , in that case, because we are integrating with respect to x'' and not to x'? I ask you so, because the comment I did at the end of my question says that they anticommute if the variable with respect to which we integrate is the same in the functions $ \delta $ and $ \psi $ (f in my comment) , which is not the case, and this is why I couldn't use that relation. I'm sorry if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: The $d/dx^\prime$ "commutes" with the integral $\int dx^{\prime\prime}$, not the Dirac delta. You move the integral inside and the derivative outside so that you compute only second integral in my answer. That is, $\int d/dx^\prime f(x^{\prime\prime}) dx^{\prime\prime} = d/dx^\prime \int f(x^{\prime\prime}) dx^{\prime\prime}$